# html - make every tr change color on hover

Tags: html, css, row

I have a table with a lot of table rows. Every table row have a `2px solid grey` border.

My problem is that the table is a link and to show that to the user I will make the border black when hovering. But adding `:hover` to tr does only apply to the hovered tr but I want all tr to get a black border.

Is that possible?

Comment: `table:hover tr {border:2px solid black}` ... Try

Comment: perhaps you should post some images to explain what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
tbody:hover tr{
    border:2px solid grey;
}
```

to restrict the hover to only the rows in the body. See this [**example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fhtpkvn9/1/)